# SO profile page not opening

Tags: bug, status-completed, error-message

Opening My profile getting **Oops! Something Bad Happened!**, other SO users profiles are getting opened but not mine.

Comment: I have the same with mine profile, in a private session it works, logging out and logging back in didn't resolve the issue. Confirmed serverside issue

Comment: What is this? Why is this happening?

Comment: On it! I pushed a bug that was not doing proper null checks. A fix should be up soon.

Comment: Thanks @js12 for the transparency. Much appreciated!  SO has an excellent team.

Comment: @js12 It is working now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed! Thank you for reporting this :).

Comment: Yeah it's working fine now :)